# Access Azure file share using DFS entry inside container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, containers, azure-file-share

My On-premise windows server and Azure file share have same folder structure or hierarchy.
I have DFS entry which is pointing to on-premise server. I am using DFS entry to map using "net use" and CmdKey command inside windows container. When try to access any file kept on windows server using DFS , it is accessible.
Now, we have changed the pointing so DFS is pointing to Azure File share. But now container is not able to access files kept on Azure file share.
I have verified the permissions of account which is used for mapping. Everything looks fine.

Can anyone share some inputs what can be the issue/fix?